# Optiplex 960 w/ one VGA output trying to add a second monitor please see pictures for better explanation

Tags: multiple-monitors, hdmi, vga, dvi

I have an optiplex 960 with only 1 vga port only (no DVI port )(no HDMI port)

- one vga cable
- one DVI cable
- two monitors with VGA/DVI ports

I'm trying to connect the second monitor any ideas ? I have searched online but have not found anything helpful ? please see images for better explanation

[image: back of cpu]

[image: monitor #1]

[image: back of cpu]

Answer (score 2):

Your [Optiplex](https://www.dell.com/support/article/bm/en/bmbsdt1/sln286358/optiplex-960-visual-guide-to-your-computer?lang=en#Back_panel_connectors) has a [DisplayPort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DisplayPort) connector. Simply purchase a DisplayPort to DVI dongle or cable.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add some hardware that offers additional video outputs. This could be either a half-height video card, which are usually pretty cheap, or a USB-based video adapter, which are usually more expensive and complicated.

If you had hoped you could split the existing output, forget it. You cannot. The only option is to add some hardware that will give you more video outputs.